# Subscribing the current member via Postmaster

Tags: postmaster, mailchimp

I have a template that is called when a user wants to subscribe to the newsletter. It is formatted like this...

```
  {exp:postmaster:campaign:subscribe
    service="MailChimp"
    api_key="XXXXX"
    list="XXXXX"
    email="{email}"
  }
```

However the email part doesn't seem to load. How can you make it subscribe using the current member's email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the EE parse order. The email tag doesn't parsed before the tag. I just updated Postmaster to parse CURRENT_USER as the current logged in email. So this should work in the next update (1.4.7). Send an email to support@objectivehtml.com if you want a copy of the latest code before the official release.

```
{exp:postmaster:campaign:subscribe 
    email="CURRENT_USER"
    service="Mailchimp"
    api_key="XXX"
    list="XXX"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've upgraded to 1.6.0 and this is still an issue.  I get this error: EMAIL must be provided - An email address must contain a single @  using the above code

Comment: I take that back.  I decided to wholesale delete the plugin, not just overwrite files.  This did the trick... works like a charm!!!